# Switch of group of cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

In this function the group of cell is A1, B1 and C1 but i want to switch for B1, C1 and D1 and after C1, D1 and E1 how can i do it

```
function regle() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var i = i+1
  var p = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var t = spreadsheet.getRange('C1').getValue();

 if (t == 1 && p == 1){
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setValue(1);
}
  else{
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().setValue(2);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create a loop that checks those groups of columns? How many?

Comment: yes 10 will be fine